# Binding listbox to observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need some help to correctly bind an ObservableCollection to xaml. I can bind the data correctly but when the data changed, the changes did not reflect on the screen. I have read related blogs and seemed to have understood, but when trying to apply what I know into my own sample, it does not work quite as I have thought.

I have 2 classes Fruits and Fruit, where Fruits is a observablecollection of fruit which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
namespace TestCommand.Models
{
    public class Fruit:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _fruitname;
        public string FruitName
        { get
            {
                return _fruitname;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fruitname!=value)
                {
                    _fruitname = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FruitName");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _fruitcolor;
        public string FruitColor
        {
            get
            {
                return _fruitcolor;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fruitcolor != value)
                {
                    _fruitcolor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FruitColor");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _selected;
        public bool bSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selected != value)
                {
                    _selected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("bSelected");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}

    namespace TestCommand.Models
    {
        public class Fruits
        {
            private static ObservableCollection<Fruit> _fruitList;
            public static void Add(string f, string c)
            {
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = f,
                    FruitColor = c,
                    bSelected = false
                });
            }
            static Fruits()
            {
                _fruitList = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Mango",
                    FruitColor = "Yellow",
                    bSelected = false
                });
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Mango",
                    FruitColor = "Yellow",
                    bSelected = false
                });
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Water Melon",
                    FruitColor = "Green",
                    bSelected = false
                });
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Apple",
                    FruitColor = "Red",
                    bSelected = false
                });
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Banana",
                    FruitColor = "Yellow",
                    bSelected = false
                });
                _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
                {
                    FruitName = "Orange",
                    FruitColor = "Orange",
                    bSelected = false
                });
            }
            public static ObservableCollection<Fruit> getAllFruit(bool bSelected = false)
            {
                var result = (bSelected ?
                                            _fruitList.Where(x => x.bSelected = true).ToList<Fruit>()
                                            : _fruitList.ToList<Fruit>());
                return new ObservableCollection<Fruit>(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

My xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestCommand.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCommand"
                xmlns:MyCommands='clr-namespace:TestCommand.Commands'
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow"
                Height="350"
                Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation='Vertical' Margin='10'>
        <ListBox x:Name='MyList' ItemTemplate='{StaticResource FruitTemp}'>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name='AddFruit'
                        Height='auto'
                        Width='auto'
                        Content='Add New Fruit 2'
                        Margin='0,10,0,0'
                        Command='{x:Static MyCommands:TestButtonCommand.AddFruit}'>
            <Button.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command='{x:Static MyCommands:TestButtonCommand.AddFruit}'
                                                Executed='CommandBinding_Executed'
                                                CanExecute='CommandBinding_CanExecute' />
            </Button.CommandBindings>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
namespace TestCommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyList.ItemsSource = Fruits.getAllFruit();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Fruits.Add("Durian", "Green");
        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My ItemTemplate

```
<Application x:Class="TestCommand.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCommand"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key='FruitTemp'>
                <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'
                                        Margin='5'>
                    <TextBlock x:Name='tbName'
                                         Text='{Binding FruitName}' 
                                         Margin='10,0,0,0'
                                         Width='100'/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name='tbColor'
                                     Text='{Binding FruitColor}'
                                     Margin='10,0,0,0'
                                     Width='100' />
                    <!--<CheckBox x:Name='cbSelected'
                                        Content='Selected'
                                        Checked='{Binding bSelected}' />-->
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I clicked on the button, I saw item added to the collection but the collection was not refreshed on the list. I must have not tied the collection correctly or may have missed something as I am very new to wpf.

Your help to point out my overlook is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method creates a new `ObservableCollection` and returns it. You assign that to `MyList.ItemsSource` (that's not a binding, that's just an assignment), and then you add an item to a different `ObservableCollection` somewhere else.

```
MyList.ItemsSource = Fruits.getAllFruit();
```

...

```
public static ObservableCollection<Fruit> getAllFruit(bool bSelected = false)
{
    var result = (bSelected ? _fruitList.Where(x => x.bSelected = true).ToList<Fruit>()
        : _fruitList.ToList<Fruit>());
    return new ObservableCollection<Fruit>(result);
}
```

Of course you don't see any new items in the *copy* of `_fruitList` that you handed to the `ListBox`.

The `ListBox` has to have the same actual collection object that you're adding objects to.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Fruit> getAllFruit(bool bSelected = false)
{
    return _fruitList;
}
```

Whoops, no filtering.

And that's still not the right way to do this. Write a viewmodel with a public `Fruits` property that returns an `ObservableCollection<Fruit>`, and use a `CollectionViewSource` in your XAML for filtering. We can walk through all that stuff if need be. You already know how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you're on your way.

## Update

I did a quick rewrite of the Fruits application as an MVVM thing. Usually I'd do the AddNewFruit command as a property of the viewmodel with a delegate command, but I didn't feel like writing a delegate command class and pasting it in. What's here is OK though.

ViewModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Fruits.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Fruit : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Fruit()
        {
        }

        public Fruit(string name, String clrString)
        {
            FruitName = name;
            //  Parse colors like so: (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(clrString);
            FruitColor = clrString;
        }

        public Fruit(string name, Color clr)
        {
            FruitName = name;
            FruitColor = clr.ToString();
        }

        private string _fruitname;
        public string FruitName
        {
            get
            {
                return _fruitname;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fruitname != value)
                {
                    _fruitname = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FruitName");
                }
            }
        }

        private String _fruitcolor;
        public String FruitColor
        {
            get
            {
                return _fruitcolor;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fruitcolor != value)
                {
                    _fruitcolor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FruitColor");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected = true;
        //  NOTE: I renamed this property
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region MainViewModel Class
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();

        }

        #region ShowSelectedFruitOnly Property
        private bool _showSelectedFruitOnly = true;
        public bool ShowSelectedFruitOnly
        {
            get { return _showSelectedFruitOnly; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _showSelectedFruitOnly)
                {
                    _showSelectedFruitOnly = value;
                    FruitsView.Refresh();
                    OnPropertyChanged("ShowSelectedFruitOnly");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion ShowSelectedFruitOnly Property

        #region Add Methods
        public void AddNewFruit()
        {
            Fruits.Add(new Fruit(NewFruitName, NewFruitColor));

            NewFruitName = "";
            NewFruitColor = "";
        }

        public void AddNewFruit(string name, string color)
        {
            Fruits.Add(new Fruit(name, color));
        }

        public void AddNewFruit(string name, Color color)
        {
            Fruits.Add(new Fruit(name, color));
        }
        #endregion Add Methods

        #region NewFruitName Property
        private String _newFruitName = default(String);
        public String NewFruitName
        {
            get { return _newFruitName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _newFruitName)
                {
                    _newFruitName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("NewFruitName");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion NewFruitName Property

        #region NewFruitColor Property
        private String _newFruitColor = default(String);
        public String NewFruitColor
        {
            get { return _newFruitColor; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _newFruitColor)
                {
                    _newFruitColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("NewFruitColor");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion NewFruitColor Property

        public ICollectionView FruitsView { get; private set; }

        #region Fruits Property
        private ObservableCollection<Fruit> _fruits;
        public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits
        {
            get { return _fruits; }
            private set
            {
                if (value != _fruits)
                {
                    _fruits = value;

                    FruitsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Fruits);

                    FruitsView.Filter = FruitFilterPredicate;
                    FruitsView.Refresh();

                    OnPropertyChanged("Fruits");
                }
            }
        }

        protected bool FruitFilterPredicate(Object o)
        {
            if (ShowSelectedFruitOnly)
            {
                return (o as Fruit).IsSelected;
            }

            return true;
        }
        #endregion Fruits Property
    }
    #endregion MainViewModel Class
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application 
    x:Class="Fruits.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fruits"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    >
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ColorSwatch" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Stroke="Gray"
                            StrokeThickness="1"
                            >
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key='FruitTemp'>
            <StackPanel 
                Orientation='Horizontal'
                Margin='5'>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name='tbName'
                    Text='{Binding FruitName}' 
                    Margin='10,0,0,0'
                    Width='100'/>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name='tbColor'
                    Text='{Binding FruitColor}'
                    Margin='10,0,0,0'
                    Width='100' />
                <ContentControl
                    Width="16"
                    Height="16"
                    Style="{StaticResource ColorSwatch}"
                    Content="{Binding FruitColor}"
                    />
                <!-- The problem here was you were trying to bind Checked, an event, 
                instead if IsChecked, a bool? property. 
                -->
                <CheckBox 
                    x:Name='cbSelected'
                    Content='Selected'
                    Margin='10,0,0,0'
                    IsChecked='{Binding IsSelected}' 
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Fruits.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fruits"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedCommand
            x:Key="AddFruit"
            />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding 
            Command='{StaticResource AddFruit}'
            Executed='AddFruitCommandBinding_Executed'
            CanExecute='AddFruitCommandBinding_CanExecute' 
            />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation='Vertical' Margin='10'>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowSelectedFruitOnly}">Selected Fruit Only</CheckBox>
            <ListBox 
                x:Name='MyList' 
                ItemsSource="{Binding FruitsView}"
                ItemTemplate='{StaticResource FruitTemp}'
                />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Label Width="100">New Name:</Label>
                <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding NewFruitName}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Label Width="100">New Color:</Label>
                <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding NewFruitColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                <ContentControl
                    Style="{StaticResource ColorSwatch}"
                    Margin="2" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Content="{Binding NewFruitColor}"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button 
                x:Name='AddFruit'
                Height='auto'
                Width='auto'
                Content='Add New Fruit 2'
                Margin='0,10,0,0'
                Command='{StaticResource AddFruit}'
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Fruits.ViewModels;

namespace Fruits
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();

            ViewModel.AddNewFruit("Jackfruit", "Yellow");
            ViewModel.AddNewFruit("Watermelon", "ForestGreen");
            ViewModel.AddNewFruit("Apple", "Red");
            ViewModel.AddNewFruit("Banana", "Yellow");
            ViewModel.AddNewFruit("Orange", "DeepSkyBlue");

            ViewModel.Fruits[0].IsSelected = false;
            ViewModel.Fruits[1].IsSelected = false;

            ViewModel.FruitsView.Refresh();
        }

        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as MainViewModel; } }

        private void AddFruitCommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.AddNewFruit();
        }

        private void AddFruitCommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute =
                ViewModel != null
                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewModel.NewFruitName)
                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewModel.NewFruitColor)
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Standard HTML color names ([see System.Windows.Media.Colors for WPF predefined color constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)) will work for the colors, and so will `#RRGGBB` or `#AARRGGBB` hex colors.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, when you use the `CollectionViewSource` you will have the ability to have filtering at xaml level. However CVS doesn't go well with ObservableCollection so I would use just an `IEnumerable` of some sorts, I will leave the choice to you. Tthat's my 2 pence. [here](https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) is a good link.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett: Thank you for pointing out the flaw. Never have thought about that! Thank you so much! Will try your suggestion

Comment: @Ed Plunkett: Would you mind walking me thru the steps I need to take should I want to convert my stuff into a MVVM? You do not need to go in details should you do not have time but the main important steps. I currently have the Models where I defined Fruit deriving from INotifyPropertyChanged, and class Fruits being an ObservableCollection to detect the event of change from fruit. How should the viewmodel be linked to xaml?

Comment: @user1205746 See update. I changed a bunch of stuff (and added a few ideas, to illustrate things you can do with WPF); read through it all and ask any questions you've got.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: That is amazing to see the VM in action! Awesome! So I did not understand what I read totally until your rewrite. As another bonus, I can see more binding in action. It is nice to know that we can dynamically bind to what was bound. (What you did in the resource style settings). It is absolutely amazing!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user1205746 You're welcome! See update, I added filtering. I'd forgotten how miserable the CollectionViewSource thing is. Filtering doesn't really belong in the viewmodel but it's the easiest way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: You read my mind! I had issue with how to do the filtering with checkbox and you answered my question before I had the chance to ask... :)

Comment: @user1205746 Ha, cool. The only thing you'll notice is that the filtering won't refresh when you add items or uncheck them. You can easily figure out how to force a refresh (see the ShowSelectedFruitOnly setter), but to make it refresh when Fruit item properties change, you'll have to add a handler for the `PropertyChanged` event of each Fruit. I think the user experience is acceptable the way it is, but that's a judgment call.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: You read my mind again!! If the list is dynamic and will be read from a database, your suggested method will also be applicable, right?

Comment: @user1205746 See further updates to MainViewModel and one change to the MainWindow() constructor. I couldn't just handle Fruits.CollectionChnaged and refresh FruitsView whenever it changes, because... the last item in FruitsView gets doubled if I do that. I can't figure why. Maybe it's a bug, I have no idea. Anyway, I've rewritten it so if the viewmodel replaces the Fruits collection, it'll recreate and refresh FruitsView.

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance. This is just a sample that I made up to illustrate my question only. And I received a very interesting, fully developed and fun sample that illustrates lot of wpf techniques. Lot for me to digest and learn. This forum is awesome! learning from you guys is more efficient than reading pages of Microsoft documentation that gave me crossed eyes all the time. Yuk!

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I have looked carefully. Your suggestion works and there is no duplication. You have marked 2 items in the constructor with selected flag being false and when you unchecked the selected check box, those items showed up and appeared that it was doubled up, which gave us the wrong impression. I was fooled by that as well but it is now debunked!! :)

Comment: @user1205746 Whoops -- sorry to throw you a curveball! Glad you got it working.

Comment: I learned a lot... it was fun. I am now trying to see if I can save this data set into a sql server database. Read some sample from Microsoft but it seemed to me that it is pretty trivial. I prefer to have a dependency injection that can transfer smoothly the memory model into the database model. Another learning curve. If I can not figure it out, may be I need to ask another question. Understood the sample is one thing, knowing how to apply it in my sample is another thing...ahhh..

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I have a quick question to clarify my understanding. Microsoft talks a lot about MVC. Is MVC specifically for website or can it be also applicable to desktop application? In MVC, it has dependency injection used with entity framework, if MVC is only applicable to web development, do you know the corresponding module/service applicable to desktop version of the application?

Comment: @user1205746 There's a generalized ["model-view-controller" design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller), which can be applied anywhere, though the details will vary a great deal depending on architecture. It's cool. With WPF, we usually use [a variant of it called "Model-View-ViewModel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–viewmodel). If the two took turns biting my ass, I couldn't tell them apart without reading the nametags. But I'm a dirty flea-bitten neanderthal with no computer scientological educmatations.

Comment: @user1205746 Now, there's also Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC framework, which is a specific framework/class library/etc. for applying one interpretation of the MVC pattern to web applications with ASP.NET. It's nice, I've used it. But I don't think you could use that framework for anything but web development on IIS.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: how about asp.net core with entity framework? Can that be used with the Model-View-ViewModel pattern you mentioned above? I just need to narrow down what I need to read before I hit my head against the wall.

Comment: @user1205746 If I were using ASP.NET Core I'd either look at ASP.NET MVC6, or one of the JS frameworks like Angular or React (warning: I wasted three days this winter trying to find a React tutorial with code that actually worked). Depends on what you know best already, and what you think is worth learning. I googled "MVVM web development" and found [this, from 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33065599/424129). But in web development terms, 2011 might as well be the Older Dryas.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I am going to submit a question regarding how to using entityframework core with wpf. Basically, it seems to work but the compiler complained that there was no key for the database while it clearly does have one. If you have come across the same situation, I would appreciate you sharing your expertise.

Comment: @user1205746 I don't know Entity Framework at all well. Lots of people around here do, though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Just posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503424/the-entiy-type-requires-a-primary-key

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Believe it or not, I am still studying the code you provided last week. I am still at this point learning from it and trying to digest it. I have a curious question for you though: Why would you have to bind ItemsSource for the listbox using an ICollectionView - FruitsView and not using the datacontext - ViewModel? I apologize in advance if you think this is an obvious question.All I know is it would not work if I use ViewModel but can not find an explanation for it. I would appreciate it if you could enlighten me.

Comment: @user1205746 The CollectionView provides filtering. You could bind to Fruits instead of FruitsView, if you didn't care about filtering for selected items.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No wonder. Now, instead of binding to ICollectionView, can I bind it to DbSet, assuming I do not care about filtering? Another question is if it is possible to derive a class from DbSet which also implements ICollectionView, then bind the ItemSource to that class?

Comment: @user1205746 I don't know anything about DbSet. I'd google "WPF binding DbSet ItemsSource". If DbSet does filtering already I wouldn't bother with collectionview. But I'd try CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myDbSet) before subclassing anything. Or google that too.

Comment: @user1205746 As a rule with WPF, you don't implement a lot of interfaces to get stuff done. Aside from INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand, always look for an out-of-the-box implementation (and with ICommand there are a few). People sometimes think they have to try to implement INotifyCollectionChanged and it's like, dude. You have so much to live for. You don't have to do this to yourself.