# PM scaffold-dbcontext not creating a primary key

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am reverse engineering our db.  I am using scaffold-dbcontext in the package manager console with the -force flag.  I know for sure it is updating the files.

I have added a Primary key in the db though and when that didn't work I even added another Index:

[image]

The dbcontext that was created seems to have the code for the Primary Key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DealerDisclaimers>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.DealerDisclaimerId)
            .HasName("PK_DealerDisclaimers");
```

However, when I try to navigate to a page that would load that table it gives the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'DealerDisclaimers'
>   requires a primary key to be defined.

The DealerDisclaimers class the scaffold-dbcontext builds out looks like this:

```
public partial class DealerDisclaimers
    {
        public int DealerDisclaimerId { get; set; }
        public int DealerId { get; set; }
        public string GeneralDisclaimer { get; set; }
        public string LeaseDisclaimer { get; set; }

        public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
    }
```

Side note: If I add the [Key] attribute then it loads without the error.  But I shouldn't have to manually add it, the scaffold-dbcontext command should prepare everything for me.

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503424/error-the-entity-type-requires-a-primary-key

Comment: It says "You need Entity Framework to be able to set the value of ID. This means the property needs to have a setter." but I have a setter already, and the scaffold-dbcontext should be creating all this stuff automatically

Comment: What does your DealerDisclaimers class look like?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: It sounds like you have found the fix for your error. Are you sure scaffold-dbcontext is supposed to do what you expect it to do (prepare the primary key without having to add the [Key] attribute)?

Comment: @Samir I know it's a pretty old question, but did you find an answer? I have a PK in the database, I'm using `scaffold-dbcontext` with `-DataAnnotations -Force` flags, but the `[Key]` attribute is not created

Comment: @IshThomas sorry man.  That was a while ago, I can't remember what I did.

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding `-DataAnnotations` to the scaffold code added the key appropriately for me.

So my script looked like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Force -DataAnnotations
```