# Error: The entity type requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to follow some tutorial on Entity Framework Core. This tutorial takes the code-first approach on creating the database. When I'm trying to run the first migration, this error shows:

> The entity type 'Value' requires a primary key to be defined.

The exact message is as follows:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Value' requires a
>   primary key to be defined.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqliteModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1()
>   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider
>   p)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
>   factory)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) The entity type 'Value' requires a primary key to be defined.

(could someone edit this msg because it looks horrible and I'm not able to fix it?)

I've double checked if I have **Id** property in the **Value** class and I've added [Key] to it just to be sure. 
I've also restarted my laptop as it could have to do with an instance of server running from previous testing sessions or something like this.

My model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DatingApp.API.Models
{
    public class Value
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
using DatingApp.API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DatingApp.API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base (options) {}

        public DbSet<Value> Values {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace DatingApp.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(c => c.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
               // app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

And connection string:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DatingApp.db"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The thing I wrote in the terminal:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

EDIT:

> ```
> D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API>dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -v
> Using project 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj'.
> Using startup project 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj'.
> Writing 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\obj\DatingApp.API.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
> dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\B590\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp24D5.tmp
> ```
>
> /verbosity:quiet /nologo
>   D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj
>       Writing 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\obj\DatingApp.API.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
>       dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\B590\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2B8C.tmp
>   /verbosity:quiet /nologo
>   D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj
>       dotnet build D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo
>
> ```
> Compilation succesfull.
>     Warnings: 0
>     Errors: 0
>
> Time passed: 00:00:02.25
> dotnet exec --depsfile D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\DatingApp.API.deps.json
> ```
>
> --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\B590.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig
>   D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\DatingApp.API.runtimeconfig.json
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\DotnetTools\dotnet-ef\2.1.4\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll"
>   migrations add InitialMigration --assembly
>   D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\DatingApp.API.dll
>   --startup-assembly D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\DatingApp.API.dll
>   --project-dir D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\ --language C# --working-dir D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API --verbose --root-namespace DatingApp.API
>       Using assembly 'DatingApp.API'.
>       Using startup assembly 'DatingApp.API'.
>       Using application base 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1'.
>       Using working directory 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API'.
>       Using root namespace 'DatingApp.API'.
>       Using project directory 'D:\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\'.
>       Finding DbContext classes...
>       Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
>       Finding application service provider...
>       Finding IWebHost accessor...
>       Using environment 'Development'.
>       Using application service provider from IWebHost accessor on 'Program'.
>       Found DbContext 'DataContext'.
>       Finding DbContext classes in the project...
>       Using context 'DataContext'.
>       System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Value' requires a primary key to be defined.
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel
>   model)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqliteModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1()
>          at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>          at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>          at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider
>   p)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
>   factory)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String
>       outputDir, String contextType)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action)
>       The entity type 'Value' requires a primary key to be defined.

Comment: Could you provide link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/build-an-app-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-from-scratch/?start=330  it's on Udemy but it's not entirely free to watch

Comment: Can you post the output from the `dotnet ef …. ` command with `-v` or `--verbose` appended at the end (i.e. [verbose output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options) option). Also which EF Core version are you using? Looks like 2.1, so shouldn't you use the new [BuildWebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options) pattern as described in the [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I've edited the question to post the output.  Yes, I'm using 2.1 EF Core Version. As I've stated, I'm learning from the tutorial, I'm not yet sure about more options of DbContext creation. I'm going to read about this pattern, thanks for the link.

Comment: I've created ASP.NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller) from scratch and everything is fine. Can you create new project, perform that migration and if everything is correct transfer all your code to new project?

Comment: @Yuriy N. it worked on a different laptop. No idea why, though

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your project which we could not find based on your current code. Could you share us the demo project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: the entity type requires a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503424/error-the-entity-type-requires-a-primary-key)