# dotnet core 2.2 EntityFramework with postgres

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I followed the [documentation on Postgres C# website](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco).

When I run this code I get:

> The entity type 'Bar' requires a primary key to be defined.

POCOs:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to avoid using `string` as a property type of Bar and let the entity framework handle JSON serialize, deserialize. I don't want the `Bar` to be a separate table. I want it to be a JSON column on `Foo`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Entity Framework requires a Primary key (Identity) on every table. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key)

Comment: But I want it to be a json and I don't want the `Bar` to be an another table

Comment: Even if it's not going to be in the database, it still needs a primary key as a property of your POCO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503424/error-the-entity-type-requires-a-primary-key)

Comment: I added the Id, it creates a new table for `Bar`. I don't want a new table to `Bar`.  I want to use a json column

Comment: @NodeJs See answer below

Comment: It shows up as null after adding [NotMapped] because it gets ignored

Comment: Try this post for your needs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core)

Comment: But these will store json blob as string not a "json". Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to .NET Core 3.0 from 2.2 everything worked fine. The following is the new csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
        <AssemblyName>App</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>App</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create `ValueConverter<Bar, string>` or use function expressions directly in `HasConversion` in on `OnModelCreating`.

Example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(x => x.Bar)
        .HasConversion(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
        v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(v));                

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with .NET Core 2.1 and MySQL and this is what resolved it for me. I'm not able to update to 3.0 at this time. Adding Ignore was the part that solved my problem.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Bar>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
           .Property(x => x.Bar)
           .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(v))
           .HasColumnType("json");
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm that adding `modelBuilder.Ignore<MyModel>()` has to be used along with `HasColumnType("jsonb")`.