# C# EFCore HasConversion to an object But EF Recognize Object Like an Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, implicit-conversion

I have a question about HasConversion in EFCore.
I decided to save in DB a model like a json String then I decided to implement automatic conversion of this Object with .HasConversion method in Configure Method of EFCore.

I have use this method in with Enum-> String and all run perfect but using this approach with object the situation become more complex:

I simplify scenario:

```
public class ObjectA 
{
    public string A {get; set;}
}

public partial class EntityA
{
    public ObjectA objectA {get; set;} //this is my json object in DB 
}
```

So I have a column in DB nvchar that i want to converto to ObjectA when I extract from DB.
As EF core documentation say, i implemented a conversion class

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityA> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.ObjectA)
            .HasConversion(y => JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                y,
                new JsonSerializerOptions()
            ),
            y => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ItemList>(
                y,
                new JsonSerializerOptions()
            )
        );
    }
```

and when this mapper run all seams ok. But i use it in query for redeem object and convert it i have this error.

```
The entity type 'ObjectA' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

but ObjectA is not an Entity/Table so where is the problem?

I have same error even if i try to add-Merge theoretically EF should read conversion and it shouldn't automatically see the AbjectA as an entity but simply a string.

Sorry for my english i hope is all clear.

Tanx in advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: the entity type requires a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503424/error-the-entity-type-requires-a-primary-key): `This exception message doesn't mean it requires a primary key to be defined in your database, it means it requires a primary key to be defined in your class.`

Comment: ObjectA is not an Entity so is useless set [Key] in Property

Comment: i have try to add a property with annotation [Key] but nothing change

Comment: Storing the column in the DB as a JSON text string is OK.  Using EF to represent a complex object in the DB is OK.  I think the problem is that maybe you expect too much of EF :(  SUGGESTION (one of several different options): Add a "serialize()" and a "deserialize()" method to class ObjectA, then invoke the appropriate method whenever you write or read the EF object.  Do this *INSTEAD* of adding a HasConversion() method in your EntityTypeBuilder.

Comment: This was my plan B, but before i have decite to ask here if exist a solution about this problem tank you.

Comment: I think with EF Core 6 you're going to have to live with the offline conversion against a unmapped typed column. With EF Core 7 you should be able to map the ObjectA to be recognizable as a JSON object/column, and possibly even query-able.

Comment: IMHO add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the object to avoid all model creation conventions. This is particularly useful if your json type has nested classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, after returning the project and fixing the code the error would show up again. I then understood that the error was due to the fact that I had added the same ObjectA object in a new model but I had not inserted the Mapper in the IEntityTypeConfiguration.

So my code is correct.
Thank you all